# ASP.NET MVC Get Month/Day/Year properties of DateTime to inherit validation attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, data-annotations, model-binding, unobtrusive-validation

I've got 3 custom DropDowns for `DateTime` model properties, each representing Day/Month/Year that set a hidden input with each value, with an also custom model binder that works fine.

I also have created a `RequiredIf` validation attribute with client side validation and it works fine both server and client side adding the corresponding `data-val-requiredif` attributes to the hidden inputs where the selected DropDown value is stored.

The problem comes when I use this `RequiredIf` attribute on DateTime property using the custom control.

```
[RequiredIf(...)]
public DateTime Start { get; set; }
```

and the issue is in each dropdown hidden input generated with `Html.HiddenFor` (binded to `Start.Month` in this example):

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Month must be a number." id="Start_Month" name="Start.Month" type="hidden" value="">
```

The problem is pretty clear, the validation attribute is on the `DateTime` property, not it's `Month` subproperty, so the `data-val-requiredif...` validation attributes are not set on that input.

**Question**:

What is the best approach to make `Day/Month/Year` inherit the dataannotation validation attributes from it's `DateTime` model?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do what you're asking.  You can't map 3 different fields to a single data validation using standard MVC validation.  What you should be doing is NOT using a custom model binder, and instead validating each field as a separate int, then combining them into a date on the server if everything passes.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch You are right, I think I overthought this and got blind, yours is probably a far easier approach.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't use data attribute names with multiple hyphens like your "data-val-number". I've also had issues with upper case so always use one hyphen after data and always lower case.

If you're passing the date back to a controller in separate pieces (i.e. month / day / year), you'll have to put it back together in a DateTime format on the server for the validation to work.

If you're putting the date together in a JSON model to pass back to the controller, MVC will convert the JSON to a model object for you. Make sure your JSON model is exactly the same as what the controller parameter is expecting.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not the point, my binding is working fine, the problem has to be with Day property inheriting the data attributes from Start parent.
PD: the "data-val" you mention is something the microsoft.unobtrusive.validation sets and it is working just fine